# Show: $\text{lcm}(a,a+p)=\text{lcm}(b,b+p), p \;\text{prime}\implies a=b$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

> (Romania Mathematical Olympiad). Let $a,b$ be positive integers such that exists a prime $p$ with the property $lcm(a,a+p)=lcm(b,b+p)$. Prove that $a=b$.

What I could do: WLOG $p|a, p \nmid b \implies a=pk, k \in \mathbb{Z}. lcm(pk,pk+p)=lcm(pk,p(k+1))=pk(k+1). lcm(b,b+p)=b(b+p)$

We want to prove that is impossible to $pk(k+1)=b(b+p)$, but I don't know how.

Comment: But $p$ doesn't divide either $b$ or $b+p$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr but what if $k(k+1)$ does?

Comment: It's not relevant, the left-hand-side of the equation is divisible by $p$ while the right-hand-side isn't.

Comment: @MichaelBurr ohh, ok. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer after **reading the comments**:

WLOG $p \mid a, p \nmid b$.

This implies that $pk=a, k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then, $lcm(pk, pk+p)=lcm(pk,p(k+1))=pk(k+1)$, and $lcm(b,b+p)=b(b+p)$

So it suffices to prove that it is impossible to $pk(k+1)=b(b+p)$, that is true because $p \mid pk(k+1)$ but not $b(b+p)$. Hence we are done.

Comment: How are you writing "WLOG $p \mid a, p \nmid b$"? Why is it the case that $p$ divides exactly one of them?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani if p divides both, then $pk(k+1)=pq(q+1) \implies k=q \implies a=b$. If p doesn't divide any, $a(a+p)=b(b+p) \implies a=b$. If we prove that: if p divides one but not the other, $a=b$, we can prove the vice-versa. In this case as $p \mid a, p \nmid b \implies a \neq b$, but as we get in a contradiction, then $a=b$.